# How to solve the issue of tomcat default page on the live web hosting?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8, tomcat9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU9pR.jpg)

This tomcat default web page is coming. Front not coming and when tried to run the backend then error 404 is coming as per my host vendor. What to do to remove this as it is present in live-mode not in localhost.

Comment: Do you have a default page in angular? and did you check your back-end running in postman or insomnia?

Comment: @Sachin1729 Hi actually my back end is not running. Yes default page is not coming only tomcat page is there.